# Is there any noun in English which changes the first letter in the plural?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, vocabulary, irregular

Plenty of nouns change the *second* letter to become plural (*man*->*men*, *goose*->*geese*) but does anything change its first letter.  I've hunted high and low over the internet, and spent ages browsing the questions at [Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/vocabulary-questions) but I can't find anything.

Comment: A related question springs to mind - what's the earliest-positioned consonant that changes on forming the plural? But maybe I should save that for another question if this one is well-received.

Comment: Plural doesn't have anything to do with letters. Plural has to do with sound; spelling is just this rubegoldbergy way we have to represent the words. It looks like it ought to represent the sounds, but it doesn't.

Comment: The phenomenon of the changing initial letter that you are describing is known as *mutation*. Here's [Wikipedia's description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_Welsh_morphology) of how it works with Welsh (though as far as I can determine, it isn't  involved in pluralizing nouns in that language). I don't believe there is any English word where initial-letter mutation occurs in the pluralization process.

Comment: You mean like how in Sindarin, the plural of *orc* is *yrch* or the plural of *adan* is *edain*?

Comment: @ErikKowal Then what do you call *man/men, goose/geese*?

Comment: Very unlikely. Only if there is a word that has been borrowed together with its plural from another language; which hardly ever happens except from Latin and Greek. The kind of word I'm think of is _Bantu_, which is the plural of _Muntu_ or _Umntu_ (not sure if this is true in any particular Bantu language, or whether this is a reconstruction only).

Comment: @ColinFine I was assuming it would have to have been imported reasonably recently, yes.

Comment: @ErikKowal: in Germanic languages, the process is known as _umlaut_, or _i-infection_.

Comment: @Colin: I think most Bantu languages pluralize words by changing the first letter (which explains the road sign "Goundabout" seen in Africa by one of my relatives). But I can't imagine English adopting a foreign plural that works like this.

Comment: @tchrist, I'm no expert in Sindarin, but that's what I mean.

Comment: @PeterShor. No, Bantu languages do not, in general, pluralise words by changing the first letter. They pluralise by replacing the singular prefix by a plural prefix. Some of these pairs of prefixes have the same vowel, but most do not. I had heard that the Swahili for _roundabout_ was _kipilefti_, and so it was treated as a _ki-_ class word, pluralised as _vipilefti_. But that may be an urban myth.

Comment: @JohnLawler, I can't actually disagree with you but it's the end result I'm interested in.

Comment: Only one I could find is **cow/kine**. However, _kine_ is considered archaic but it is also mentioned as regional. I'm not sure where it is used now. It is related to Scots _kye_.

Comment: @ermanen I've just spotted that on a wikipedia article linked from a question a few clicks away - it's the first candidate for an answer.

Comment: In English, it's /kau ~ kain/. The diff between C and K is just more rubegoldbergeoning, and only exists in our imagination.

Comment: @ColinFine - Gotta stay away from those jokey German linguists and their pesky i-infections!

Comment: You’d need to find a word that starts with a vowel if you want ablaut or umlaut in the first sound of the word. So like *ago/egi* in Latin (present, perfect for a verb) or *eald, iealder, iealdest* in Old English for *old, elder, eldest*.

Comment: @ermanen Though where does that put the singular *kow* and *kowe* which have both been found in Modern English? (Though as a language-trivia question about how accepted spelling turned out, I think that's a good answer).

Comment: In French, *oeil* means “eye” but the plural changes it so that *yeux* means “eyes”. There are also the English suppletive plurals like *person/people* or *pig/swine*, but those have regular plurals as well. And the plural of *is* is *are*.

Comment: @JonHanna: Never heard "kow" or "kowe" before. I checked OED and it includes _cow|kow_ as a Scottish word:  ‘A hob-goblin; a scare-crow, bugbear’ (Jamieson); cf. worricow n.

Comment: @ermanen *kow* and *kowe* are obsolete spellings, but related to the fact that *kine* and *kye* have a *k* while *cow* has a *c*.

Comment: You need to concentrate on sounds, not letters.  The plural of *woman* is *women*, but the *o* changes pronunciation even though its letter doesn’t change whereas the *a -> e* letter change does not change the pronunciation at all.

Comment: @tchrist there are enough irregular verbs that I restricted the questions to nouns.  *Person*/*people* was what set me thinking about this - it seems like  coincidence that they start with the same letter (as they're from *persona*&*populus*).  I hadn't considered *pig/swine*, as you could equally say that the plural of *swine* is *pigs*.

Comment: @ColinFine (Re: ‘mutations’) In Germanic languages, the kind of _mutation_ that Erik was talking about doesn’t exist at all. It’s different from what in Germanic is called _mutation_ or _umlaut_, which in Celtic terms is only ever called _affection_. The Welsh mutation is what causes the difference between _tad_ ‘dad’, _ei dad_ ‘his dad’, and _fy nhad_ ‘my dad’.

Comment: @ChrisH I don’t know that *swine* can be used in the singular.  I think it’s a plurale tantum like *cattle*.  I may be wrong, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Isn’t that just lenition?

Comment: @tchrist "why not, you swine" - OK that's a different usage, but [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/swine) says "plural same" implying singular use is OK.

Comment: @tchrist _Ei dad_ is lenition; _fy nhad_ is nasal mutation. And of course, _ei thad_ ‘her dad’, which I forgot before, is aspiration. (As Erik said, none of these mutations play any part in forming plurals; they are applied based on various phonetic environments that were lost about 1,500 years ago.)

Comment: In Old Icelandic, which has more typographically represented vowel variants than English does, the first letter of some words changes between singular and plural forms—for example, between _áss_ (god) and _æsir_ (gods). We see a reflection of the split in that example in the anglicized proper names _Asgard_ and _Æsir_ (or Aesir), but to my (extremely limited) knowledge, no singular/plural pair of words in English out of Old Norse has retained a split in first-letter spelling.

Comment: @tchrist Great thought there about woman/women, but roundedness on /w/ in English is allophonic, so even if we were asking about sounds rather than letters, I don't know if it would count.

Comment: @ChrisH How would you feel about changing the question to asking about words which change their initial phoneme? It would mean cow/kine wouldn't count, but maybe many more words might. Or it might be too late to change it.

Comment: @ErikKowal: The Wikipedia article about the general phenomenon of mutation (under its many names), rather than specifically Welsh mutation, is found at [Apophony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophony).

Comment: @curiousdannii, that would be an interesting question, and quite possibly a better one than this as it stands.  I feel it would be too late to change this one - not just because of an accepted answer but because of my intent on asking the question.  It would be a harder question to research (as spelling differences are more amenable to text searching) and one that would attract some interest (not least from me).  It's yours if you want it.

Comment: What did your research so far reveal, or leave unsaid, please?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The only one I could find is ***cow/kine***.

However, *kine* is mentioned as an archaic plural of *cow* in most dictionaries including OED but Wikipedia and Wiktionary mentions as regional or dialectal also.

[Wordsmith](http://www.wordsmith.org/words/kine.html) does not count it as archaic and includes a contemporary usage:

> Kine is one of the very few words in English (other examples: I/we, me/us) that have no letters in common with its singular form, cow. It is pluralized using the -n marker, as in the words children, brethren, and oxen.
>
> "Cows stood belly deep in a ranch pond, doing their impersonation of the kine in John Constable's paintings."
>   *Verlyn Klinkenborg; Water and Grasses; The New York Times; Jul 5, 2010.*

Interestingly, *kine* is a double plural also because an extra suffix has been added to Middle English plural form *ki (ky)* or *kie (kye)*:

> The word "cow" came via Anglo-Saxon *cū* (plural *cȳ*), from Common Indo-European *gʷōus* (genitive *gʷowés*) = "a bovine animal", compare Persian *gâv*, Sanskrit *go-*, Welsh *buwch*. **The plural *cȳ* became *ki* or *kie* in Middle English, and an additional plural ending was often added, giving *kine, kien*, but also *kies, kuin* and others.** This is the origin of the now archaic English plural of "kine". The Scots language singular is *coo* or *cou*, and the plural is "kye".
>
> [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cattle)

Comment: Eyes till feal lettres read hairings force hounds.

Comment: Sounds incredibly Scottish to me. Meh, I dinnae ken.

Comment: This is the first thing that sprang to mind when I saw the question. Sidenote: rails pluralization methods recognizes kine as the plural of cow.

Answer (score 25):

I'm not sure whether pronouns count: "I" versus "We".

There are also some prefixes: e.g. "byte" versus "kilobyte"; and "ester" versus "polyester"; and possibly "pole" versus "dipole".

Comment: The prefixes don't count: bytes are clearly different to kilobytes, esters are different to polyesters.

Comment: When I asked I thought that pronouns, like irregular verbs, were boringly easy - I just didn't say so.  The reasons are probably similar as well.

Comment: Also: *one* and *many*.

Comment: Upvoted for I/We.

Answer (score 21):

The Equatorial Guinean currency, the **ekwele**, has plural **bipkwele**.

Comment: That's a neat example of a word that has to be used in its original form in English.  After comments about (southern/eastern) African languages I trawled through a few lists of words that have entered English from various African sources.  None of them appear to have brought their plurals with them, either adopting an English *-s* (e.g. [bwana](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bwana)), behaving as a mass noun (e.g. [obeah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obeah)) or having a plural form the same as the singular ([impala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impala), at least as used in Africa).

Comment: @ChrisH: Has to? You'd be amazed how many bureau de change cashiers would say *ekweles*. (deliberately not *?* because I'm uncertain what counts as 'correct' in this situation).

Comment: @TimLymington, you're right, I did put it rather strongly.  But it's as close as anything is likely to get.

Comment: (+1) I really like this answer.

Comment: Another example from the realm of currency: Lesotho has the [loti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesotho_loti), plural maloti. Since plural prefixes are a common feature of Bantu-speaking peoples like the Sotho, there are also many demonyms that form their plural using prefixes (one [Masotho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sotho_people), many Basotho) although dropping the prefix to form the English demonym is also common, as I did earlier in this sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are some that only describe plurals, so you'd have to use another word if you wanted to express singular: poultry, livestock, folk(s).